# how to replace and load a new url that is entered by a user

Tags: javascript

how do I replace the whole URL and then replace and load it with the new URL that is entered in a prompt by a user at the moment I have got this far

```
var website = prompt("enter a website");
```

document.location.href.replace = website;

I have tried different once but it adds the URL I already have. I want the whole URL replaced
[the url that needs to replaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnwcG.png)

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var website = prompt("enter a website");
window.location.href = website;
```

Comment: I tried that it shows the URL but it doesn't replace the whole of URL as I m using a local file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't replace the whole of the URL"? Can you edit your question with an example of what is typed into the prompt and what the resulting URL is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.replace()` method.

Comment: I have tried that it doesn't work because I m trying to execute a variable that the user inputs

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be using

> document.location.href

Example

```
document.location.href="https://flinkhub.com"
```

Remember to add http:// or https:// before website name for proper redirection otherwise it will add to the existing url.

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: document.location.href = "https/", website;   <<< i have put this one but only add https and does not load the website

Comment: `var website = prompt("enter a website"); //enter like https://[website-name]
window.location.href = website;` works for me 100%.

Comment: k i am using a local file and it does work but it doesn't redirect or load the page which is what i want it just adds to the local URL that I have got at the moment

Comment: i tested the code on local file also, it worked. Can you edit your answer with some example of what you are expecting. Some screenshot will also work

Comment: i have loaded a screenshot please take a look at it it's link on the question

Comment: I have recorded a video where you can see it's working. I hope that will solve your problem. https://filebin.ca/3qFKU49QBzKz

Comment: would it be possible if you can kindly paste the code as i m using public internet.

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<script>
function doit(){
 var website = prompt("enter a website");
window.location.href = website;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div onclick="doit();">Click me</div>

</body>
</html>`
I created an html file with this code. Double clicked to open it in a browser then i clicked "Click me" to open prompt then i entered website name like "https://www.google.com".